# If recursive function takes multiple args is there a performance benefit from putting the args in a struct

Tags: c

This is common in functional languages especially with TCO. I was just wondering if it provided any performance benefits besides being easier to write and keep track of. Is it just as fast to access the variables in the struct as it is to access them if they were just normal arguments? Is there any cons to this method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no benefit, because structs are passed by value. Passing multiple arguments one by one will take the same amount of allocations from a running program as the allocation of a `struct`. Moreover, `struct` may give you worse results because of padding.

Even if you pass your `struct` by pointer, you would still need to allocate a new instance of your `struct` before passing it to the next level of invocation. Theoretically, you could get some benefit by reusing a struct that you have allocated once in multiple invocations, but in most cases that would be a micro-optimization not worth your trouble (unless your profiler indicates otherwise).

Answer (score 2):

even recursion involves many stack operations which dwindle the performance more over passing arguments to the recursive functions make it even further irregular,create a confusion to developer,going with their own risk

Answer (score 2):

**Cons:**

If you have `__fastcall` available, then recursive function could get performance boost by passing multiple arguments via registers. Number of general purpose registers available for this can differ from platform to platform. All the extra arguments are passed via stack.

Chances are good that stack hosted arguments are loaded into registers at the very beginning of the function for calculations. So, every stack passed argument would require at least one memory access. If you packed everything into structure and passed its pointer, then every member access would also generate at least one access to memory. No real benefit here

Passing multiple arguments by value you have freedom to change them as you please. With structure members you either make temporary copies to use in calculations (effectively repeating passing multiple arguments) or compiler will write modified values back to where the structure instance sits. This can produce needless overhead.

**Pros:**

I would pack output-type arguments into structure. This would just lower number of arguments and make function prototype conceivable, because it is in human's nature to operate entities with features